# How can I center a commandLink inside a circular Div?

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I want to center a primefaces Commandlink element inside a circular div but it just wont work.

this is what I have right now.

```css
.createButton {

    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #2C3449;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 95%;
    top: 22px;
}
.addCustomerIcon{
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<div class="createButton">
  <p:commandLink update=":editForm" onsuccess="PF('createCustomer').show();" process="@this" actionListener="#{customerController.initialize()}">

    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x addCustomerIcon"></i>

  </p:commandLink>
</div>

</html>
```

I know that this snippet does not show anything but I think that is because of the Primefaces Tag.

So my question is. How can I center this Button inside the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.addCustomerIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me.